# UIView animation needs to be called 2 times to work

Tags: ios, uiview, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

Im trying to animate a UIView with this code:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:RegNrView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        RegNrView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

The RegNrView is a `UIView` containing a `UITextField` and has the `frame: (320,0,320,460)`.
This is called from an `IBAction`. The first call nothing happens, but the second time it works. Why does it do that?

Comment: This code looks okay.  Is anything else happening between the two calls?  Maybe the RegNrView pointer is not yet established on the first go 'round?

Comment: Or is it possible that this code is not running on the main thread?  Making UIKit calls on a non-main thread will result in funky behavior like animations taking a long time to load, actions not working when they're supposed to, or just a straight up crash.